# Reimplementation of call() method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, reinventing-the-wheel

I was try to reimplement the native `call` method in JavaScript.
Here we need to handle the object which we pass in the call function and additional params. I handle the additional params using `eval()` method. Is there any more efficient way to write it?

```
var name = {
    name: "JavaScript", 
  version: "6",
}   

function printName(location, district){
    alert(this.name + ", " + this.version + ", " + location + ", " + district);
}

Function.prototype.myCall = function(...args){
  var param = args.slice(1),
      paramLength = param.length, 
      paramString = "JSONarg.myFun(";
  for(var i = 1; i <= paramLength; i++){
    paramString += "args["+i+"],";
  }
  paramString += ")";

  if(typeof this != 'function'){
    throw new Error(this + " is not a Function");
  }

  var JSONarg =  {
    ...args[0],
    myFun: this
  }
  return eval(paramString);
}

printName.myCall(name, "Chrome", "browser");
```

Comment: Hey this is an interesting post! It appears that the code above shows an alert with the message `undefined, undefined, Chrome, browser` - is that what you expected, or was there something else you intended to have it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Review

To be quick I will just add comments to the code with some alternatives

```
// if you add to a built in prototype use Object.defineProperty or Object.defineProperties
// using the default settings
// Function.prototype.myCall = function(...args){ // use 2 parameters
Function.prototype.myCall = function(name, ...args){ 

  // var param = args.slice(1),  // is now second parameter 

  // Should be a constant
  //    paramLength = param.length, 
  const  paramLength = args.length;

  // not really a param string. Rather its a eval function
  //  paramString = "JSONarg.myFun(";
  var evaledFunc = "JSONarg.myFun(";

  // The variable if defined in the loop should be let
  // Now starts at index 0  
  //for(var i = 1; i <= paramLength; i++){ 
  for (let i = 0; i < paramLength; i++) {  // add space for ( and ) {

    evaledFunc += "args[" + i + "],";  // use spaces between operators
  }
  evaledFunc += ")";

  // This function is a prototype of Function. You would have to go hard 
  // to have the next statement be true. Just let the native exception 
  // generate the error
  /*if(typeof this != 'function'){
    throw new Error(this + " is not a Function");
  }*/

  // Does not change, thus should be a const
  // var JSONarg =  {
  const JSONarg =  {  // would be best defined at the top of the function

  // args[0] is now the param name
  //  ...args[0],
      ...name,
    myFun: this 
  // }  // there should be a ; here
  };
  return eval(evaledFunc);
}
```

Removing the comments and some minor mods we get...

```
function myCaller(name, ...args) { 
    const JSONarg =  {...name, myFun: this};
    var func = "JSONarg.myFun(";
    for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        func += "args[" + i + "],"; 
    }
    func += ")";
    return eval(func);
}
```

Rather than `eval` you could also have use [`new Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

### [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

To prevent problems (`myCall` showing up in strange places) and as it is in a very often used native type.( All functions get the new property). `enumerable = true` can slow every function call just a little depending on JS engine and version.

Add to prototype safely using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). Default accessor `configurable`, `enumerable`, `writable` are `false`

```
if (! Function.prototype.myCall) {
    Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, myCall, {value: myCaller});
}
```

### [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

With all that said there is a much easier way to do the same. [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) will bind a functions with an object (sets the functions `this`)

```
function printName(location, district){
    alert(this.name + ", " + this.version + ", " + location + ", " + district);
}
printName.bind({...name})( "Chrome", "browser");

// or just use original name obj

printName.bind(name)( "Chrome", "browser");
```

The bound function is a new reference, the original function remains unbound

```
const printNameBound = printName.bind(name);

printNameBound("Chrome", "browser");

printName("Chrome", "browser"); // will fail as not bound to name object
```

### [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

You can also use [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to do the same. In this case there is no new reference to the function created. The binding is temporary.

```
printName.call(name, "Chrome", "browser"); 

// or

printName.apply(name, ["Chrome", "browser"]); // args as array
```

Comment: How can i use new Function instead of eval()?

Comment: @Kallis `function myCaller(name, ...args) { return (new Function("name", "func", "args", "return ({...name, func})(...args);")(name, this, ...args);}`

Comment: can you check this https://jsfiddle.net/gowtham25/m1gnLd6x/12/